# regex matching by group

Tags: regex

I have this regex that matches an empty span:

```
<span></span>
```

how can I rewrite it so that it matches span or div like tis:

```
<(div|span)></{THE CORRESPONDING TAG}>
```

> performance is very important

just because everyone is asking, I use .NET regex...

Comment: We can’t do anything without the regex...

Comment: @AdamBrinded Just because it doesn't contain any characters that are treated specially by the regex engine, it doesn't mean that it isn't a regex. In Python, `"<span></span>"` is a valid regex matching the string that looks exactly as the regex itself.

Comment: @AdamBrinded '<span></span>' is the regex.

Comment: I highly suggest not using regex for parsing HTML. Use specially curated libraries for that.

Comment: @Bharel How/where can I find one?

Comment: I don't know .NET so I can't help you with that, but search for HTML parsing libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use backreferences (depending on the regex implementation, these are noted differently, I just used backslash and number of the matching group, like e. g. Java and .net regexes use it, some other regex dialects use `$1` instead of `\1`):

```
<(div|span)></\1>
```